# Why does a dialog seemingly have its one thread?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to advanced programming - but from what I've read, all my android programs are on one thread.

This means, only one line of code or method/function can be executed at a time before moving on to the next line (that's what I thought anyway).

However, I'm using a custom dialog to develop this application and yet, the program continues even after the dialog has ran. I'd like my program to wait for the dialog to close so that I can receive the input and manipulate it.

This seems fairly straightforward when programming in Java (e.g. the Scanner tool waits for the user input before proceeding as opposed to running the code following it while it waits for user input).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Everything does happen on one thread unless you explicitly tell it not to.  However, showing a Dialog happens asynchronously.  Basically, when you ask the Dialog to show, it adds that information to a list of UI events that are waiting to happen, and it will happen at a later time.

This has the effect that the code after asking the Dialog to show will execute right away.

To have something execute after a Dialog choice is made, add an [onDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) to the dialog and do whatever it is you want to do in `onDismiss`.